# how to install 64bit packeges on my ubuntu 12.04 64bit?

Tags: 12.04, multiarch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install ia32-libs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136394/cannot-install-ia32-libs)

when I try to install 64bit packages on ubuntu 12.04 64bit, package manager says :

> Error: Cannot install 'ia32-libs'

and I tried to install ia32-libs but synaptic says :

> could not all packages for instalation or upgrade. the folowing packages was unresolvable dependencies. make sure that all repositories are added anf enabaled in the prefrences .
>   ia32-libs-multiarch : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not going to be
>   installed    ia32-libs:  Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch

I want to install teamviewer. on 11.10 I installed 64bit teamviewer package withouth any problem.

Comment: I'll give it a try when i get home from work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably havent opened up the necessary repositories, heres how

**To enable Partner and Independent Repositories in Ubuntu Software Center**

Open Ubuntu Software Center and select “Edit” and then select “Software Sources”:

Make sure both Canonical Partner repositories have check marks next to them

Now open up Terminal and copy and paste

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Ariaman, please download the one for 64bit and if you still stuck with, then you have to wait until it get fixed.I have also problem with some application which were running well on 11.04 but not on 12.04.I tried with UCK but it causes zenity crashed on 12.04.

Comment: Mr. stephen myall : I did what u said but the problem still runing ! It says  :  Cannot install 'ia32-libs' . I explain it again : I have ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and I want to install teamviwer. I downloaded 64bit package from its website . whene I run it with software center or GDebi package installer it errors :  Cannot install 'ia32-libs'. what can I do ?

Comment: Did you try toinstall in from the Terminal?   sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: finally ... I had to fresh insall ubuntu and problem solved !

Comment: Congratulation!!!, Its not the first time Ive had to that myself.  You dont want to keep this question open especially if the answer I gave didnt help.  For other who come along after maybe you want to flag this this to the moderators for deletion or closure.  Im not sure it will help other in the future anyway