# WPS Kingsoft not running

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, deb

Installed WPS Kingsoft on my Ubuntu 12.10 64bit from a .deb package downloaded from [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/wps-office-for-linux-looks-like-microsoft-office-but-isnt) but when I execute any for the three files (writer, spreadsheet or powerpoint) nothing happens.

Anyone has a workaround for this?

Comment: What errors do you get if you try to run these commands from the terminal?

Comment: The download you used is a BETA. Plus it is a 32-bit package and you are using a 64 bits. Problems can be expected so you should try to find the error it throws and file a bug :)

Comment: thanks for the advice @Rinzwind, i've been away from linux for a year but i will try to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experienced the same problem running 32bit version of Kingsoft over a 64bit system. However, I use 13.04.

When I ran

> $ wps

from the terminal, I was told that `libgthread-2.0.so.0` is missing. It is part of `ia32-libs` and basically running

> $ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

solved the problem for me.

Note that on 13.10, according to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/148280/121692) `ia32-libs` is considered deprecated.