# Can't print on Canon MF4450

Tags: 13.04, drivers, 12.10, printing, canon

I've attached the printer via USB, Ubuntu finds it, installs it (both the `MF4450` and the `MF4450 (Fax)` printers, since it is a 4in1) but is not able to print even the Test Page.

I'm new to Ubuntu as main system (I was a Windows 7 user up to 2012, playing with some distro in VM but nothing more), what could I check / try ?

I tagged it both 12.10 and 13.04 since the problem was there on the first and is still present after the upgrade to the second.

Comment: Using the superkey (the windows key in windows) and then writing printing, do you see the printer icon WITHOUT any red or failure msg on it ?

Comment: I've not got your message, could you be more clear ? Should I write "printing" after pressing the superkey ? I've a localized ubuntu (ITA, and Gnome Shell, if it matters)... thanks in advance

Comment: Just go to see your printings devices ;) its under the "System Setting" --> printing or the way I mentioned, press superkey and then write "printing". check if it has some red flag attached to the printer icon or not.

Comment: also check for this [linux-driver-link](http://www.driverlook.com/canon-imageclass-mf4450-laser-multifunction-printer-driver-windows-linux-mac/) for downloading your device driver and let me know back

Comment: Sorry for the late; It is installed, no red flags, I've now reinstalled the drivers (I had 2.20, you linked 2.40, then installed 2.70 too from canon-europe); it is recognized, it is auto-powered on, but if I run print Test page, it says that it is elaborating, but then nothing happens... where can I find some logs to dig into ? Any ideas?

Comment: I refer you to the printing-debugging wiki of the ubuntu at [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems)

Comment: Amir, thanks for your help too, if you'll publish your comments as an answer I'll upvote it for sure

Comment: No need buddy. Glad you found your answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have 32bit libs installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 ia32-libs lib32z1
```

Comment: Thanks, I've read in some forums too that 32bit libs may be involved even if I've a 64bit SO and 64bit printer drivers; I've run that command and it says that there are some dependencies that cannot be resolved: `ia32-libs-multiarch` :/

Comment: like here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136394/cannot-install-ia32-libs

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch` before, then `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 ia32-libs lib32z1 
` and now it prints like a charm. I've got nothing of what I've done, but I'm happy now :D 32bit libs to make 64bit drivers on 64bit SO is something that sucks tbh