# Install Navicat on Linux Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit

At navicat wiki http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/Can_I_run_Navicat_on_64-bit_Linux%3F, to run navicat, need install all 32 bit libraries with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This command work fine before ubuntu 13.10, but on 13.10 box, me get this error :

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

I have install the suggested package :

```
lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

but navicat still won't run. Please,, help me..

Comment: "ia32-libs" has become obsolete. Have a search for a version that is about "multiarch". See this for an explanation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136394/cannot-install-ia32-libs?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing `lib32z1` `lib32ncurses5` `lib32bz2-1.0` packages,additionally you have to install `wine` to run navicat.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: owh..wine,, ok install.