# 32 bit packages in 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, package-management, 32-bit

Can I install the downloaded 32 bit packages to 64 bit OS?

*(now using UBUNTU 12.04(32bit) and going to install UBUNTU 12.04(64bit) on another PC.)*

Comment: I guess for that you will have to install `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129779/how-to-install-64bit-packeges-on-my-ubuntu-12-04-64bit) for more detailed instructions, but basically:

1. Enable partner repositories
2. Update apt-get
3. Install 32-bit libraries
4. Install 32-bit packages of your choice

Sometimes, the package will take care of the dependencies itself (particularly if you're getting it from a PPA) and all you need is for the partner repositories to be enabled.

Note: Most programs these days are available in 64-bit versions. If the program you're looking to install has one available, you should favor it over the 32-bit version, unless there are any known issues that technologically prevent you from using it (ie - it crashes on startup). 64-bit software is better equipped to leverage your hardware than 32-bit is, making it more efficient overall (and potentially allows the developers to add in features that weren't possible in the 32-bit version).