# Install 32 bit ubuntu along side 64 bit windows 8

Tags: uefi, 32-bit

I need to install Ubuntu 32 bit alongside windows 8 64 bit. Can anyone tell me how to get windows/UEFI to run the 32 bit disk?  I have disabled secure boot and gotten a 64 bit disk to run, but I need 32.  If you are wondering why, I'm trying to fix something on my phone and the tools require 32 bit linux.  I also need to either use the live DVD or actually install it.  A USB or virtual machine won't work.

Comment: May be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170810/32-bit-packages-in-64-bit-ubuntu

Comment: The instructions I was following had instructions like that for 63 bit ubuntu, but they didn't work for me.  When I asked for help on that forum, the person who wrote the instructions suggested that I use 32 bit instead.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 he wants to install 32 bit ubuntu os alongwith 64 bit windows 8 os.Not to install 32 bit packages in 64 bit machine.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hence "May be helpful".

Comment: @amschmind did your machine is a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Um, not quite sure what you're asking.  Yes, my machine has a 64 bit processor and is running 64 bit windows 8.1.  I was able to install 63 bit ubuntu, but what I need to do in it didn't work, and that's why I need to switch to 32 bit ubuntu

Comment: Just one clarification, there is no 63 bit version of Ubuntu, but 64-bits. And describe exactly why it didn't work. What happened, etc. 64-bits is the defaults when using UEFI installation hence 32-bits will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why do you think you need a 32-bit Ubuntu? Today, there's seldom any real need for this type of setup, and it does complicate a dual-boot configuration with Windows 8 in EFI mode, so I strongly recommend against it unless it really is needed.

If you really do *need* a 32-bit Linux, try this:

1. In your firmware setup utility, disable Secure Boot.
2. In your firmware setup utility, enable CSM (aka "legacy") support. Ultimately, you'll want your firmware to switch easily between BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and EFI/UEFI mode, and most offer an "automatic" setting of some sort to enable this; but for now, forcing the system to BIOS/CSM/legacy-only mode will work as well, if not better. Unfortunately, different computers have different user interfaces, so I can't tell you exactly what this option is called. You'll have to hunt for it.
3. Boot the Ubuntu medium in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Sometimes, you'll see a choice of two boot options for the medium, one of which includes the string "EFI" or "UEFI" in it and the other of which does not. Select the option that does *not* include the EFI/UEFI string to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.
4. Proceed with the Ubuntu installation normally.
5. If you set the computer to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode only, reset it to support both boot modes, if possible.

Once Ubuntu is installed, you'll need to find a way to dual-boot. Broadly speaking, there are three options:

- You can rely on your firmware's built-in boot manager to switch between EFI-mode (Windows) or BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode (Linux) boots. This is usually a bit awkward, but some people find it acceptable. Unfortunately, some EFIs have such poor user interfaces that this option is literally unavailable.
- You can use [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as your boot manager. Install it in Windows and edit the `refind.conf` file: Uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is among the options. When you reboot, you should see an option for Windows and a gray diamond-shaped icon that should boot to the GRUB that your 32-bit Ubuntu installer installed. Unfortunately, the EFI features that rEFInd uses to boot a BIOS-mode boot loader aren't available on all computers, so this option might not work for you; but if it does, it can be a convenient way to proceed.
- You can install a *64-bit* (yes, 64, not 32) [EFI boot loader for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) and configure it to boot your 32-bit kernel. I know this is possible with some EFI boot loaders, but not with all of them. (The EFI stub loader can't do it, for instance.) I'm sure that at least one of GRUB 2, Fedora's patched GRUB Legacy, and ELILO can do this job, but I can't promise that any specific one of them can do it.

Unfortunately, there are a few EFIs that are so inflexible that a BIOS/EFI dual-boot is impossible. If you've got one of them, your only hope is to use a 64-bit EFI boot loader for Linux.

Given all the caveats and the pretzel-twisting that's required to get this to work, I think you can see why I recommended sticking with a 64-bit version of Linux.

Comment: CSM was the trick.  The tool I needed to do work on my phone was specifically written for 32 bit linux.  I tried 64 bit first, both off the live disc and installed, and it didn't work.  Enabling CSM allowed me to run the 32 bit live disc.  That was all I needed, so I didn't install it (64 bit is actually still installed), but I assume I could have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can install `32 bit ubuntu` os alongwith `64 bit windows 8` operating system,but your system was a 64 bit machine.For this you actually need a bootable dvd or usb with Ubuntu 32 bit os loaded.To make a bootable ubuntu usb in windows use `unetbootin` software.

Comment: I have a bootable DVD of 32 bit ubuntu, but I can't figure out how to boot it.  UEFI (or windows or something) only seems to recognize 64 bit discs.  Once I disabled secure boot, I would see an uption in "advanced startup" to boot from another device.  That option isn't there with a 32 bit disc in the dvd drive.

Comment: put the disk in drive,and change the boot-order to dvd drive in bios.

Comment: I've tried that.  Windows is the only option in the BIOS.

Comment: I think you say about the windows option in grub.Boot into the bios,my lenovo laptop has special nova button to boot into bios.Likewise your laptop had any special button or click F2 on startup.

Comment: Yes, in the BIOS, under the "boot" tab there is only one option under "boot priorities," and that is windows.  I can add a new boot option, but I don't know what to enter for the "path for boot option."

Comment: not that,it was like boot from HDD,Network boot,Dvd drive,USB.

Comment: I know I've seen that in the BIOS of computers that I used to have, but it's just not there on this one.