# Can't install Ubuntu for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, windows-10

could someone please advise me as to where I may be going wrong... (I may need a Step-By-Step guide)

1. I have been trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows 10. I have first created a 20GB partition (unformatted) and have turned off Fast start.
2. I have formatted a flashdrive with the Ubuntu 16.04.1 32bit and this seems to work fine.
3. Problem... when I try to install Ubuntu, it finds the Windows 10 installation but only gives me the option to format the partition with Ubuntu (losing all contents)... !! how do I set it up to install alongside Windows??

Thank you all in advance.
Matt

Comment: This might help: [enter link description here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378210/install-32-bit-ubuntu-along-side-64-bit-windows-8)

Comment: @MJM is the CPU you have really only 32 bits or you just decided to use 32 bit?  If it is a 32 bit processor consider installing the 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the option "Something else". Then, look for the partition you want to dedicate to Ubuntu. Choose to use it as ext4 partition, check the checkbox to format it, and choose to mount it at `/`.

You will get a warning that the data on the partition will be lost when formatting. Double-check that you chose the correct partition, then confirm.